# Why do my IBActions not get called in pageControll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ibaction

I have a view with IBActions tied to UITextFields and UIButtons. They all work as intended unless I use that view inside of a pageControl. If I do that the UITextField IBActions don't work but the UIButton IBActions do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "page control" you mean `UIScrollView`+`UIPagecontrol`.

In this case, the problem you are facing is the "greediness" of UIScrollView when it comes to touches. A UIScrollView will swallows all the touches (like a touch black hole) and will not let other controls receive them.

One way forward is (but I am not saying that it will be easy): subclassing `UIScrollView` and overriding:

```
touchesBegan:withEvent:
touchesMoved:withEvent:
touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

so that you can dispatch the touch to your controls after verifying that they belong to them.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will probably just put UIButtons over them as that seems to work.